# Exception occurred applying plugin request[id:'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version:'1.3.40-eap-40']

Tags: kotlin, cocoapods, kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-native

```
An exception occurred applying plugin request [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm', version: '1.3.40-eap-40']
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm']
  > Cannot add extension with name 'kotlin', as there is an extension already registered with that name.
```

This error occurs in my build.gradle.kts file

Did you happen to see this error in a Kotlin Cocoapods project built from the samples provided on Kotlin/Native GitHub?

Answer (score 5):

This error occurs because in the build.gradle.kts, there are conflicting plugin imports. Like seen below:
[image]

You can't have kotlin 'Jim' plugin and 'multi-platform plugin' together, so remove the kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.31" and build your gradle project.

Also, when you remove this will be accompanied by few more errors in the dependencies section. So comment out everything from dependencies and the two compile tasks below as well and build it. It should work!